# ASP.NET Core 6 site work with kestrel not with IIS or IIS Express (503)

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I'm working on an ASP.NET Core 6 site and I usually use kestrel to run and debug the application. Today I've deployed the app to IIS but after one or two requests IIS stop responding and only return

> HTTP Error 503.0 - Server has been shutdown

Same behaviour with IIS Express. Everything works fine with kestrel.
I don't know how to debug the problem, I've attached the debug but with no luck. I've also looked at stdout log but nothing appears.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how to debug the issue ?

Comment: What you care about is how to debug the program, you can refer to my answer. Finding the key to the problem is what we need, so we provide you with a way to grab the dump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR;**
Rewrite the startup with the "new" net6 way.

**Long Story**

I even opened a ticket with MS that lasted about a month, after which they finally recommended me a workaround, to use hosting model “out of process” instead of “inprocess” in the web.config

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyProject.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" >

<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyProject.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="outofprocess" >
```

But that was just a workaround, and it turns out that out-of-process hosting doesn’t have the same performance as in-process.
I've used this solution in test for a while, lacking any other better option.

However, that left me with the sense that the problem was somehow linked to the host of the application, so I tried to rewrite the startup; I was using the old “net 5” style of Program.cs and Startup.cs, so I thought that rewriting it in the new standard could be beneficial.

Incidentally, THAT solved my original problem.

I still don’t know what was wrong in the old way and I don’t have the resources to investigate it, but after using the new “net 6” way of building the Startup, the problem of 503 with the standard “inprocess” hosting model disappeared and it has never happened again since then.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely that more than one instance of IISNativeApplication is being added to the Dependency Injection container.  The application will eventually return 503 responses even though it shows that it is still running in the IIS application pool and no exceptions were raised.  You would notice this behavior only in IIS.

To fix the problem, make sure that only one of the following is called only once anywhere in the application (typically the first line of Program.cs):

> ConfigureWebHostDefaults
> WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder
> WebApplication.CreateBuilder
> Explicit calls to UseIIS

See a detailed description of the problem here:
[IIS Support Blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/asp-net-core-503-server-has-been-shutdown/ba-p/3830338)

Comment: That makes sense. I don't have the old application raising the problem, but the sintomps are the same

Answer (score 0):

Please follow my step to collect the dump files. And if want analyze the dump files you can create a new post and ask for help. This answer just tell you how to debug issue.

---

*First Way*

**Remote debug with visual studio 2022**

1. Deploy your app to IIS.
2. [Run your VS2022 with administrator and attach the process](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/visualstudio-docs/blob/main/docs/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer.md).
3. Reproduce the issue to check the issue.

---

*Second Way:*

**Collect dump files**

If the first method can't reproduce or debug the issue.
You can follow below steps to collect the dump.

1. Download and install [`Debug Diagnostic Tool v2 Update 3.1`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102635)
2. Deploy your webapp in IIS
3. [Set rules to collect dumps by using DebugDiag](https://troubleshootingsql.com/2011/05/24/tools-tips-and-tricks-8-debug-diagnostic-and-crash-rules/) or [Collect dumps manually](https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0499200)

Comment: The issue arise either on remote IIS, local IIS and even on IIS Express. I believe it would be easier to debug the local IIS or IIS Express. I've already attached a debugger, turned off the "Just my code" option and checked every kind of exception.

Comment: @mCasamento You can try my suggestion to debug it first.